# InitializeComponent() broken when refering Sharepoint.dll

Tags: c#, wpf, sharepoint-2010

Morning!

I am trying to program against sharepoint with Linq, but have a starting problem.
I guess this might be a newbee problem, but i am one so dont shoot me.

I have created a WPF app and did not add any code. I then add a reference to Sharepoint.Client.dll and Sharepoint.Linq.dll. After this is done i get the red squigel line under InitializeComponent() telling me its not existing in the current context.

This is only a problem in WPF not regular old Windows application.

Spec:
Application is .NET 3.5 since sharepoint does not support 4.0.
Application is x64 as sharepoint is x64 only.
Everything else is default.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all, could you check if the target framework of your project is actually set to .Net 3.5?

Secondly, make sure that the Build Action for the xaml file (in the Properties window) is set to "Page"

If neither of these options solve your issue, could you please post the root node declaration of your xaml file (i.e. `<Window x:Name=....`). There might be a problem there.

Comment: Thanks for answering. This is the XAML: <Window x:Class="Mobile_Support.MainWindow" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"> <Grid> <ListBox Name="ListBox1" Height="225" Width="150" /> </Grid> </Window>

Comment: @Hans'v Skogen: Ok, make sure that both the namespace (Mobile_Support) and class name (MainWindow) are identical in MainWindow.xaml.cs and MainWindow.g.cs (found in obj\x64\Debug)

Comment: Mornin and sorry for late reply.. I checked the files you are pointing to and they have identical namespace and class name. I find it strange that it stops working once i add some sharepoint dlls as reference..